# How can I overwrite my _getitem_ function？

Tags: python, deep-learning, pytorch, resnet, image-classification

Now I have to read 2 images from my training set as the input of my resnet-34 model.But the original Dataset and DataLoader can not finish my task.I have to customize my Dataset class,but I don't know how to overwrite its function.

My dataset looks like ' data_set/train/img1,img2,img3.........',i need to get the images 2 by 2,return 2 images and their label(such as 'C01'),how to make my Dataset?

I tried to create one like this but failed.

```
class MyDataSet(Dataset):
"""customize my dataset"""

def __init__(self):
    self.images_path = None

def __len__(self):
    return len(self.images_path)

def __getitem__(self, item):
    img1 = Image.open(self.images_path[2*item])
    img2 = Image.open(self.images_path[2*item+1])
    label = self.images_class[item] # I don't know how to return the label of 2 images.

    if self.transform is not None:
        img1 = self.transform(img1)
        img2 = self.transform(img2)

    return img1,img2, label
```

[image]

Comment: What do you mean by "have to read two images"? Is your intention to create a mini-batch of size 2 to run through the resent or you have some customised model version which takes two images being a single sample from the dataset?

Comment: 'you have some customised model version which takes two images being a single sample from the dataset' This is true.I am doing the first step,rewrite the Dataset class,since the original Dataset and DataLoader just get 1 image from the dataset.After finishing this,I should modify my resnet network to get as an input 2 images,instead of 1.

Comment: What I want to do is 'get 2 adjacent images from the training set each time as a training sample->concatenate them into a 6-channel image->modify the network input channel to 6 channel->input that image to the network'.

Comment: Each training sample has 2 images,including 2 photos of the same leaves taken under different light conditions.

Comment: Maybe you can refer to the existing answers.

Answer (score 0):

After reading your comment, I see what you mean:

```py
class MyDataset(Dataset):
    def __init__(self):
        self.images_path = None

    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.images_path)

    def __getitem__(self, item):
        img1 = Image.open(self.images_path[2*item])
        img2 = Image.open(self.images_path[2*item+1])
        label = self.images_class[2*item]
        # for example, label = xxx1(and xxx2), you need return xxx
        # str
        label = label[:len(label) - 1]  # return xxx
        if self.transform is not None:
            img1 = self.transform(img1)
            img2 = self.transform(img2)
        # we need to concatenate the two images
        img = torch.cat((img1, img2), dim=0)
        return img, label
```

For example, for two images 11 and 12, after processing, you will return an image with a channel number of 6 (11 and 12 are concatenated), and the label of this image is 1 (if it is 21 and 22, the returned image label 2).